# Respodning to GET request with ExpressJS then executing RequestJS request inside

Tags: node.js, express, requestjs

Currently I am just making a call to an API, specifically the Ticket Master Discovery API, and this returns a JSON object just fine:

```
//PACKAGES 
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request'); 
var router = express.Router(); 


request('https://app.ticketmaster.com/discovery/v2/venues.json?keyword=UCV&apikey=' + apiKey, 
 function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body);
    return;// Print the google web page.
  } 
    else {
      console.log(error); 
  }

});
```

I would like to utilise ExpressJS's 'get' to respond to a get request and then make a 'request' call (as shown above) inside of that - is this possible or is my understanding incorrect? I've gone ahead and read the documentation, and understand each in their simplest of forms but I'm still struggling.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a basic example:

```
const express = require('express');
const request = require('request');

const app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {

    request('https://app.ticketmaster.com/discovery/v2/venues.json?keyword=UCV&apikey=' + apiKey, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            res.send(body);
        } 
        else {
            res.send(error);
        }
    });

})

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Server listening on 3000');
})
```

If you run this code and then browse to http://localhost:3000/ then you should see the ticketmaster.com response.

Comment: Thanks for this, going to give it a proper go when I get home. Currently I'm using the Cloud9 IDE in my browser and it just seems to skip 'Server listening on 3000', despite me going to my project's URL.

Comment: @Zach No problem :) Ah, Cloud9 sets a port that you have to use. If you're using Cloud9 then you'll need to replace `3000` with `process.env.PORT` in `app.listen(...`

Comment: BOOM! Thanks, Dan! When i go to the project's URL it returns the JSON object :)